# Spark ignores timezone of a timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have tried to load to a spark data frame but seems like it ignores the timezone of a timestamp and uses spark timezone instead. Here is a code to run it.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import os
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Europe/Moscow")
df = spark.createDataFrame([
       Row(user_id = 'user_id', time=pytz.timezone("UTC").localize(datetime.combine(datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime.min.time())))
    ])
for row in df.collect():
    print(row['time'])
    print(pytz.timezone("UTC").localize(datetime.combine(datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime.min.time())))
df.show()
```

Here is the output in this case

```
2020-01-01 03:00:00                                                             
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
+-------+-------------------+
|user_id|               time|
+-------+-------------------+
|user_id|2020-01-01 03:00:00|
+-------+-------------------+
```

Could you please tell me if it's expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Spark respects the zoneid set in the configuration.
Here are some examples to understand.

+05:30 => My timezone i.e Asia/Calcutta

+05:00 => Pakistan

+03:00 => Moscow

Using default timezone or systemtem timezone ( here +05:30 for India )

```
println(java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault.toString)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault.toString)
spark.sql("""
select id, cast('2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00' as timestamp) ts from range(1) 
""").show(false)

Asia/Calcutta
+---+-------------------+
|id |ts                 |
+---+-------------------+
|0  |2020-01-01 05:30:00|  //Midnight in London is morning 5:30 in India
+---+-------------------+
```

Cast a timestamp that is having Pakistan zone info

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault.toString)
spark.sql("""
select id, cast('2020-01-01 00:00:00+05:00' as timestamp) ts from range(1) 
""").show(false)
+---+-------------------+
|id |ts                 |
+---+-------------------+
|0  |2020-01-01 00:30:00| //Pakistan midnight is 30 mins past midnight in India
+---+-------------------+
```

Now change the setting to "Europe/Moscow"

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Europe/Moscow")
spark.sql("""
select id, cast('2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00' as timestamp) ts from range(1) 
""").show(false)


+---+-------------------+
|id |ts                 |
+---+-------------------+
|0  |2020-01-01 03:00:00| //Midnight in London is 3 hrs past in Moscow
+---+-------------------+
```

Another example:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Europe/Moscow")
spark.sql("""
select id, cast('2020-01-01 00:00:00+05:00' as timestamp) ts from range(1) 
""").show(false)

+---+-------------------+
|id |ts                 |
+---+-------------------+
|0  |2019-12-31 22:00:00| // Midnight in Pakistan is 2 hrs away for Moscow.
+---+-------------------+
```

Note: If there is no zoneinfo, simply the "datetime" part is attached to the  zoneid configured.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Europe/Moscow")
spark.sql("""
select id, cast('2020-01-01 00:00:00' as timestamp) ts from range(1) 
""").show(false)
+---+-------------------+
|id |ts                 |
+---+-------------------+
|0  |2020-01-01 00:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you specified timezone as UTC while using pytz module that's gives you output as `2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00`. But you specified timezone as Europe/Moscow in spark timezone config so you will get `2020-01-01 03:00:00` (UTC+3).

If you specify timezone as UTC for spark config then you will get same answer as you get from pytz module.

```
>>> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
>>> df.show()
+-------+-------------------+
|user_id|               time|
+-------+-------------------+
|user_id|2020-01-01 00:00:00|
+-------+-------------------+
```