# Why difference when importing csv with spark

Tags: postgresql, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, intellij-scala

I have this csv file, payments.csv, for some particular rows the timestamp is changing by itself. the first 3 lines are the screenshots for easier understanding.

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col,when,to_date,row_number,date_add,expr}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{Window}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
//Importing the csv
val df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("payment.csv")


val df2 = df.filter($"payment_id" === 21112).show()
val time_value = df2.collect(){0}{5}
println(time_value)
```

clueless about it as of now.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Inserted screenshots

Comment: Try `df.printSchema` to see what datatype is being inferred.

Comment: Most likely related to the time zones used. What is the setting for your server and what for the client?

Comment: You may check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68838344/spark-ignores-timezone-of-a-timestamp

Comment: @Frank heikens- sorry for this, but since the timezone is already included in the cell, wouldn't it automatically adjust because of that ? is it possible that SQL does not adjust whereas spark does .. as in spark adjust the timedifference between this timezone and our current timezone

Comment: @Vikramsinh Shinde -- |-- payment_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- customer_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- staff_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- rental_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
 |-- payment_date: timestamp (nullable = true)

Comment: @Dymtro Mitin - Thanks for uploading the screenshots.